# How to set 0 x 0 = 1 in a element-wise array multiplication? MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, multiplication, elementwise-operations

I have two column vector A and B of same length n.

In both vectors, there are only 3 possible values for their elements: -1, 0 and 1.

When I multiply A by B element-wise, I hope to get the expect results for 1x1, 1x(-1) and (-1)x(-1).

However, here, when 0 is a term in the multiplication, I'd like to get the following results:

0x0    = 1

0x1    = -1

0x(-1) = -1

Element-wise multiplication is easy in MATLAB:

`times(A,B) or A.*B`

I'd like know how to set up a predefined result for an operation, say, 0x0 =1. Knowing this one, I'll be able to deal with the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override the `times` function ([see here](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103129-how-do-i-overload-built-in-matlab-functions)), but it's easier to do the operation manually as follows: multiply normally and then replace the `0` results (which correspond to either `A` or `B` equal to `0`) with the modified value (`1` if `A` and `B` are equal and `-1` otherwise):

```
A = [1 -1 0 1 1 0 1];
B = [1 1 -1 -1 0 0 1];
result = A.*B;
ind = result==0;
result(ind) = 2*(A(ind)==B(ind))-1;
```

You can also do it as follows in one line, but less efficient:

```
result = A.*B + ~(A&B).*(2*(A==B)-1);
```

This gives

```
A =
     1    -1     0     1     1     0     1
B =
     1     1    -1    -1     0     0     1
result =
     1    -1    -1    -1    -1     1     1
```

Comment: Note that is is typically a BAD IDEA to alter or overload standard functions if you don't absolutely have to. -- So definitely go with something like the above 'manual' implementation if possible. Of course you can implement it in a function if desired, just call it `myTimes` rather than `times`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first one is really creative!

Comment: @Mason Glad I could help